# How to access my own news feed and videos, photos I share?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm just making a simple widget where I can display my facebook feed as customized, like grid view.

When I was submitting for app review, there was so much permission when it was my own feed only. I have no plans for visitors to like login into my site. It's just my own feed on my site on grid view.

Are there other simple ways to do this rather than graph API? Simply to get my facebook feed as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for your own account, you do not need review. Review is only neccessary if you want to enable other users to use your App - or, for example, if you want to get data of Pages you do not own.

Just use a User Token with the correct permissions to get your account data with the Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. I'm a bit lost with the API, can you point me where or how would I let know facebook that I'm using my app to access my personal data only? I can't see an option like this

Comment: you do not need to let them know. just use the api.